# PHP Cut unknown file extensions

Tags: php

I need help about file manipulation in PHP.
I have 4 file with known names and UNKNOWN extensions. 
Like that:

```
Y923BBBB.E120506
Y924BBBB.E120606
Y925BBBB.E120706
Y926BBBB.E120806
```

and the file extensions changes everyday.
How i can cut or strip for every file the file extension, so that will stay only the names like that:

```
Y923BBBB
Y924BBBB
Y925BBBB
Y926BBBB
```

Anybody an idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [strrpos](http://php.net/strrpos) to find the last `.` and [substr](http://php.net/substr) to get only the substring up to that point. To find the files and rename them, use [glob](http://php.net/glob) and [rename](http://php.net/rename):

```
foreach(glob('*') as $f) {
    if ($f == '.' || $f == '..') continue;
    $stripped = substr($f, 0, strrpos($f, '.'));
    rename($f, $stripped);
}
```

Comment: Hi,
THX for your help, I have try your code but he didn't delete the file extension. And how can i delete the file extension when he is not known next time?

Comment: Hi, It works very good now, i have forget to use rename ;-)
It stays only the problem how to get or to find the name of the file extension? any idea?
THX

Comment: OK i found solution with exec on cmd.
THX for everybodys help.

cheers

Comment: Wow, it is perfect. I love it. Great work THX very much. Cheers

Comment: Technically this can be a correct answer. However, there are some caveats: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10928496/367456

Answer (score 2):

Think about it the other way around: you want to *extract the filename*, not "delete the extension":

```
echo pathinfo($file, PATHINFO_FILENAME);
```

http://php.net/pathinfo

Comment: No, not to extract, i want to rename the files in the folder, without the unknown file extensions.

Comment: -_-;; Sorry, I can't do more than show you how to get the data you want, you'll have to understand it yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Take care that [`glob('*')`](http://php.net/glob) works differently on windows and linux ([compare with answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10910868/367456)). Use [`DirectoryIterator`](http://php.net/DirectoryIterator) instead if you want a more stable code. Also that one [provides the needed functions already](http://php.net/SplFileInfo) to process the file-extension and won't break - as in this example - when a file does not have a dot inside. And take real care with `rename`, using `glob` returns the file-name only, `rename` handles this as full path, you will move files to locations you might not want to move them.

```
foreach(new DirectoryIterator('.') as $f) {
    /* @var $f splFileInfo*/
    if (!$f->isFile()) continue;
    ($ext = strlen($f->getExtension())) && $ext++;
    if (!$ext) continue;
    $path = $f->getRealPath();
    rename($path, substr($path, 0, -$ext));
}
```

Take care. You should always takes care with rename operations. Every operation related to the file-system and changing it needs more care as let's say read-only proceedings.

Comment: Hi sorry for my late response. I have try your code and i get this message:   Fatal error: Call to undefined method DirectoryIterator::getExtension() in d:\dir\rename.php on line 5.          That ist this line:     ($ext = strlen($f->getExtension())) && $ext++;                 Do you know what is wrong there or if i forget something to change?
THX